# NotMachingCheckSumError in Tensorflow_datasets

Tags: anaconda, spyder, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I want to build a model in tensorflow 2.0 using the 'celeb_a' dataset in Spyder (Anaconda3).

When running this code:

```
celeba_bldr = tfds.builder('celeb_a')
celeba_bldr.download_and_prepare()
```

I get the following error:

```
NonMatchingChecksumError: Artifact https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlRnM, downloaded to C:\Users\Home\tensorflow_datasets\downloads\ucexport_download_id_0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlDDaXUAQO8EGH_a7VqGNLRtW52mva1LzDrb-V723OQN8.tmp.3706deb2f0c24dcfbc0d2de880c8aa70\uc, has wrong checksum.
```

I have no idea how to overcome this error.

Does anybody have a solution for this error so that I can download the 'celeb_a' dataset?

Comment: same issue here, on colab notebook

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes server was bad due to which it fails to take requests from data server that's why you are getting this error, I tried it now it works fine see this [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-jgFwOg2mEw6j5HXM_4RtfXSVInSkCdw) notebook.

Also I tried to register checksum so that if there is any problem with that but it is correct see [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19qXX0UXdpNgiD8znPxFA2Ie9EL2iQEoq) . So problem occur due to bad server. Try it again it works.

Comment: Than you for answer. I will try again.

Comment: I get the same error, with the exact same wrong checksum. Perseverance did not help.

Comment: @cwilmot I just check it again it works for me [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NoKMp6Z62HCeflmRfkdLO2OO5n3v1X9Z?usp=sharing). Which `tfds`  version you are using? update it to the latest one and try again, If done already then maybe there are some server issues in your region by data providers, so try again after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating `tensorflow-datasets`.

[Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-datasets) is very outdated having version 1.2 while [PIP](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-datasets/) already has 4.4.